# Change the color of silverlight AutoCompleteBox when user hovers the item

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, blend

As title, when user hovers to select the item in the expanded listbox, there is a background color that highlight the text. How can I change that background color? i tried couple things by editing the template, but I have a hard time getting it...

```
<Style x:Key="AutoCompleteBoxStyle1" TargetType="sdk:AutoCompleteBox">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MainBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MarkerBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BasicBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:AutoCompleteBox">
                <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened"/>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Text" IsTabStop="True" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                            <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">

                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0">
                                <Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1"/>
                                </Border.RenderTransform>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource StrongBrush}"  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <ListBox x:Name="Selector" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{StaticResource StrongBrush}" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"  ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Try This

```
<Style TargetType="input:AutoCompleteBox">
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000" />
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="45" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="input:AutoCompleteBox">
            <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                <TextBox Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsTabStop="True" x:Name="Text" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="0" />
                <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <system:Boolean>true</system:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </ToolTip.Triggers>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    <Grid Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" />
                        <Path Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                    <Grid Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}">
                    <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="0" BorderThickness="0">
                        <Border.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="1" />
                        </Border.RenderTransform>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#11000000" />
                        </Border.Background>
                            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="1.0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="-1" />
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="#AADDDDDD" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <ListBox x:Name="Selector" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="0" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="PopupOpened" />
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="PopupClosed" />
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpened">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1.0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <system:Boolean>True</system:Boolean>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```